# mup deploy Timed out error with a wrong Pushing address

Tags: amazon-ec2, meteor, mup

I am trying to do a `mup deploy` manually after running the `mup init` successfully.
But I am receiving this error message below-

```
ubuntu@dev-ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:~/myapp/spa/meteor-api/.deploy$ mup deploy
Building App Bundle Locally
                                                                            
Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor App
[1.2.3.4] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:695:19)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:697:14)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  level: 'client-timeout'
}
```

I have run the `mup init` using my `mup.js` file. I didn't run the `mup deploy` from the same way because it shows me an error message saying `.deploy` is not a meteor app.

Now do any of you know what is the issue here and why i am getting this error messsage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that `mup` was not able to connect to your EC2 instance. Make sure to include the correct credentials (IP, username and pem file path) in you `mup.js` file.

You can test this by running `mup ssh one`

Comment: I have added only hostname and username in the mup.js file but no password or pem. Instead, I am using the SSH authentication from the .yaml file. It works fine until the mup deploy. Any Idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: @IstiakMahmood I m sorry but I have not worked with ssh yaml auth. `mup setup` and `mup ssh one` works fine but `mup deploy` is not?